# Выборка уникальных записей за заданный год

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть первоначальная таблица test

```
+---------------------+------+
| dt                  | id   |
+---------------------+------+
| 2017-01-01 11:00:00 |    1 |
| 2016-12-31 11:00:00 |    1 |
| 2017-01-01 11:00:00 |    2 |
| 2016-12-31 11:00:00 |    2 |
| 2017-01-01 11:00:00 |    3 |
| 2017-01-02 11:00:00 |    3 |
+---------------------+------+
```

необходимо сгрупировать по дате и посчитать кол-во уникальных id (здесь все понятно)

```
SELECT DATE(dt) AS date, COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS count1 FROM test GROUP BY date;

получаем:
+------------+--------+
| date       | count1 |
+------------+--------+
| 2016-12-31 |      2 | <- здесь id 1,2
| 2017-01-01 |      3 | <- здесь id 1,2,3
| 2017-01-02 |      1 | <- здесь id 3
+------------+--------+
```

**а теперь вопрос:** необходимо в вывод внедрить еще один столбец "count2", который бы отображал количество id (COUNT), но только если записей с таким id не существует в столбце "dt" 2016 года (и ранее 2015, 2014 и т.д), а существует только в столбце "dt", относящемуся к 2017 году.

Т.е в идеале должно получиться что-то такое (count1 должен по-прежнему оставаться из прошлого запроса)

```
+------------+--------+--------+
| date       | count1 | count2 |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 2016-12-31 |      2 |      0 | <- 0 т.к id 1,2 также имеются и в 2016 году (в столбце dt)
| 2017-01-01 |      3 |      1 | <- 1 т.к id 1,2 имеются в 2016 году, а id 3 нет (считаем только его)
| 2017-01-01 |      1 |      1 | <- 1 т.к id 3 отсутсвует в 2016 году
+------------+--------+--------+
```

за отсчетный год можно взять текущий 2017 (но это необязательно), т.е логика такая, что если записей с таким id нет в прошлых годах, увеличивать значение count2

Comment: @Mike поясните, при чем тут 1-0 если надо подсчитать количество?

Comment: подзапросом то не пробовали считать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select date(dt), count(distinct A.id), count(1)-count(B.id)
  from test A
  left join (
   select id
     from test where dt < date_format(curdate(),'%Y-01-01')
    group by id
  ) B on A.id=B.id
 group by date(dt)
```

Подзапрос `B` возвращает список id, которые встречались ранее чем 1 января текущего года. который по left join подклеивается к основным данным. Посчитав количество подклеивщихся записей получим количество id встречавшихся ранее 2017, остается только вычесть его из общего количества записей за этот день

Comment: Благодарю! в целом все "срослось", единственное, вместо "count(1) - count(B.id)", указал "count(distinct A.id) - count(B.id)", чтобы результат подзапроса отнимался от значения первого счетчика

Comment: @Andrei первый счетчик, если за один день было две записи с одним id (с разным временем) даст 1 ибо ищет уникальные id за день. А `count(B.id)` даст 2 потому что уникальность не проверяет. Так что если вычитать как вы, то писать надо `count(distinct A.id) - count(distinct B.id)`, но лично я решил так не делать ибо distinct медленнее ...